# How to read C# method output from javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have a C# class method that return a xml document not file.
How to read C# method output from javascript???
I don't wont to use script manager.

Any ideas?

Comment: Accept some answers, or no one will want to answer your questions.

Comment: 8 questions, and no accepted answers... @harold - click on your name, then click on each question, read the answers, then accept the best one. If there are no good answers, follow up until you get one. You may need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar Question was asked in this thread

[call a vb.net subrouting from a javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579382/call-a-vb-net-subrouting-from-a-javascript-function)

In ajax you can use jQuery, very simple to use if you don't want to use script manager.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific. Are you creating a control that has client functionality or you just need to expose the XML on the client? In the first case you can pass it through a script descriptor, in the second, you can use a web service and call it from javascript. Please provide more details.